# Finding position of inner path within outer path edges along known axis

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics, sprite-kit, trigonometry

I am looking for an algorithm to calculate a position of a closed path contained within another closed path so that its center point is along a known axis and its the closets to the outer path's edge as much as possible (without intersecting it).

The paths are most likely to be simple shapes (oval, rectangle) but would be nice if there is a more general algorithm that can work with more complex paths (i.e. represented by CGPath/BezierPath).

Better illustrated by these examples:

[image]

In all three cases, I have **point A**, **point B** and **Path 1** / **Path 2**.

I am looking for the position of **point P**, which is the center of **Path 2** and places it closest to the edges of **Path 1** along the axis **A-B**

Is there a general way to achieve this or do I need to calculate it for specific shapes separately?

(the 3rd example is obviously easily solved when dealing with circles only, but this is just one specific case)

I am using SpriteKit on iOS, so if there are any existing API that I can take advantage of, great. But pointers to a general algorithm would help too.

Comment: No solution, but might be part of it: [Separate Axis Theorem](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/84029/algorithm-to-verify-if-a-shape-is-inside-another)

Comment: This might also be something for the computer science stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep this as general as possible, I would go for a dichotomic search. That way you can be completely agnostic about your paths, as long as you have a black-box function that tells you whether paths intersect.

This comes to mind and would be really simple because you only have one parameter, that is a 1D problem. Then you have a simple characterization of the position of P with a real number t in [0,1] : `P = A + t * (B - A)`, and thus a small space of possibilities for P.

I will suppose you have a function `contained` that, given both paths, A, and P, returns `true` if and only if the Shape2 is entirely contained in Shape1 ("without intersection" as you define it).

Then some pseudo-code for this algorithm could be the following :

```
Point find_P(Path1, Path2, A, B)
{
    if( !contained(Path1,A,Path2,P) )
        throw ("Impossible for P == A !");
    else if( contained(Path1,B,Path2,P) )
        return B;

    double dt = 0.5;
    Point P=A, V = B-A;

    while(dt > eps) // where eps is your precision parameter
    {
        if( contained(Path1,A,Path2, P+dt*V ) )
             P += dt * V;
        dt /= 2;
    }
    return P;
}
```

Comment: To add to this, when you move up to more complicated shapes, it might help to work with a simple bounding path (box, or circle, or something else simple, as long as you can generate a reasonably tight bound around your complex shape) until you have a good estimate, and then refine the estimate to a solution using the actual shapes. That would help save on computation time... Also, you could use a binary search along A-B relatively similarly to the above, which might converge faster in certain cases, but not necessarily always...

Comment: That particular project is on hold for now but this looks like a reasonable approach that can work with various shapes. I will give it a try once I resume working on the project. Thanks.